# How does `[][]` match "either [ or ]"?

Tags: regex, grep

Consider:

```
$ echo 'a [b][c]' | awk -F '[\\]\\[]' '{print $2}'
b
```

That makes sense to me as a valid regex for `[` or `]`.

Yet this also works:

```
$ echo 'a [b][c]' | awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'
b
```

And similarly in grep:

```
$ echo 'a [b][c]' | grep '[][]'
a [b][c]
```

But I don't understand how.  `[][]` appears to be "match no characters" (ie, `[]`) twice in a row.  What is happening?

Comment: "Match no characters" is not allowed. If `[` is immediately followed by `]`, the rule is that the `]` does not close the character class (because "match no characters" is illegal) but rather contributes to the class. You can see an example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) in the discussion of `[:punct:]`.

Comment: Actually, in many (most? java and ruby at least) languages `[]` produces an `Empty char-class` error.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks.  I suspected something like that was happening, but I'd like to find a specific reference in the bash or awk docs.  Apparently this isn't universal as [ruby doesn't seem to like it](https://rubular.com/r/Ar729itzg2Nf06)

Comment: @Bohemian Traditionally, regexps don't use escaping to escape `]` and `-` inside character classes. They required these characters to be put into special positions that couldn't be mistaken for their normal use.

Comment: I think PCRE introduced escaping there, and generated that error message.

Comment: "[Additionally, if you place ‘\]’ right after the opening ‘[’, the closing bracket is treated as one of the characters to be matched](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See list item `1` in "RE Bracket Expression" in the POSIX regexp spec (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05):

```
The <right-square-bracket> ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list
```

Given that, `[][]` represents a bracket expression `[...]` that contains a list of 2 characters, `]` and `[`.

Using backslashes to escape `]` within a bracket expression instead is non-POSIX but which some versions of some tools will accept - YMMV.